# Create XML with JSF

Tags: java, xml, jsf, jakarta-ee

I need to send XML to the browser with my JSF application. This XML is generated by the application.
I try to create it but my JSF application sends HTML every time.

How can I change the content-type to send xml ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Doing it in JSP is a bit nasty.

As already mentioned you can use a **Servlet** and inject/load your variables in there. Eg by accessing the session context:

```
MyBean myBean = (MyBean)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                         .getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("myBean");
```

Or you can output it to the **HTTP Response** from a method in your Backing Bean. Eg:

```
try {
    String xml = "<person>damian</person>";
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    final HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)ctx.getExternalContext().getResponse();

    resp.setContentType("text/xml");
    resp.setContentLength(xml.length());
    resp.getOutputStream().write(xml.getBytes());
    resp.getOutputStream().flush();
    resp.getOutputStream().close();

    ctx.responseComplete();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or if you are using **Facelets** you can set the response type in the `<f:view>` tag.

Comment: Why is the JSP tag "nasty"? If you have a page that delivers XML then it seems like the logical thing to do?

I guess it boils down to whether he wants to output an XML stream as in your example or whether he wants to define the XML structure in the JSP and use his backing-bean to fill in the data elements.

Comment: True. There may be some situations where rendering it on the page could be "useful" but IMO it's usually nasty. Same goes for doing it via Facelets or any other "view" framework.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the content-type within your JSP. I assume you are using a JSP and creating the xml content from a backing bean? A JSP like this would output XML:

```
<%@page contentType="text/xml"%><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<portfolio>
  <stock>
    <symbol>SUNW</symbol>
    <name>Sun Microsystems</name>
    <price>17.1</price>
  </stock>
  <stock>
    <symbol>AOL</symbol>
    <name>America Online</name>
    <price>51.05</price>
  </stock>
  <stock>
    <symbol>IBM</symbol>
    <name>International Business
    Machines</name>
    <price>116.10</price>
  </stock>
  <stock>
    <symbol>MOT</symbol>
    <name>MOTOROLA</name>
    <price>15.20</price>
  </stock>
</portfolio>
```

You could then easily change these hardcoded values to be bean values from your backing-bean in the way you would normally do for HTML-outputting JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a servlet return XML rather than the JSF stuff. I take JSF (and JSPs and any other UI layer) as returning "human readable" content. XML is machine readable.

RE: Session data - I've never done this, not used JSF just know it as a UI layer, but a quick google returns: http://blogs.oracle.com/chrisf/entry/retrieving_jsf_session_variables_in

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the [content-type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) (sec. 14.17) of the returning page as `text/xml`. It'll currently be set as `text/html`.

Browsers have used a variety of mechanisms to determine the type of the data being returned, but the proper, most reliable way is to set the HTTP `Content-type` header.

I'm sorry - I'm not JSF knowledgeable, so I can't advise on how to fix this, but it gives you something to look for now!

Comment: Yes I would like to set this content-type but I don't know to do this in JSF page.

Answer (score 0):

Here you've got some sample code to do it in a **facelet**:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:define name="metadata">
        <f:metadata>
            <f:event type="preRenderView" 
                listener="#{clientManager.initialize}" />
        </f:metadata>
    </ui:define>

    <f:view contentType="text/xml">
        <ui:repeat var="client" value="#{clientManager.list}">
            <client>#{client.name}</client>
        </ui:repeat>
    </f:view>
</ui:composition>
```

Like the way it does when rendering HTML, JSF evaluates its own tags and renders your xml tags to use as they are.