# How to get value parameter from xml in Icefaces page/JSF page?

Tags: xml, jsp, jsf, icefaces

i want to get the value from xml response in jsf page,can i do it?

in netbeans,when i create the icefaces page,then the java backing bean also created..

can i do it in jsf page or in my backing bean?

cause we usually getting thing done using Servlet,i have searching and googling a lot about this stuff,and i found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327491/create-xml-with-jsf) but,if taht link,is creating not getting value from xml response..anybody can help me?

thanks in advance..and sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want your XML data in your Application?

Usually Managed Bean acts as the Servlet for JSF or ICEFACES. If you want to store your data in servlet then you can go for managed bean.