# JSF how to respond with xml data

Tags: java, xml, jsf

I have a silly question. How can I send XML data as a response when using JSF?
I have ManagedBean with simple getXmlData method (returns XML String). I want to send that data as a http://host.my/file.xml for example.
I know it's tryvial problem, but somehow i just can't deal with it.

Comment: Why not use a Servlet?

Comment: JSF is the wrong tool for the job. Before posting an answer, what container are you targeting? Tomcat? JBoss? GlassFish? Anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use a Servlet, you'll have to get the HttpServletResponse from the FaceletContext und write directly to that. See [Create XML with JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327491/create-xml-with-jsf)